# Type Error: cannot read undefined when mapping through an API

Tags: reactjs, api

I am working on a React app that uses the NYT books API (it will be a searchable app). I added it successfully, but when I go to map the API following what my tutorial did I am getting an error The Type Error Cannot read map of undefined.

I looked through the API's JSON to make sure I am calling the correct field with dot notation and it looks like I am and I have tried a couple other options as well. My code is below, thanks!

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Book from './Book.js';



const App =  () => {


const APP_ID = "4f3f9c74-74cd-4bc4-a21d-80ac92d41a29";



const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);


useEffect (()=> {
getBooks();

},[]);

const getBooks = async () => {
const response = await fetch("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=hAzLGYxE9ydMH30QAdJYNIF333jiz0nX");
const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);

};

return(
  <div className="App">
<form className="search-form">
<input className="search-bar" type="text"></input>
<button className="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>

</form>
{Object.results.books.map(book =>(
<Book />
))}  

  </div>


);


};


export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

As at the time your app renders, data isn't ready because you're making a network request

Try using a ternary operator

```
data ? data.map(()=>{
  //
})
: null
```

for your case, i don't where your response data is contained, so try either of these this two snippet:

```
{Object ? Object.results.books.map(book =>(
<Book />
)) : null}
```

or

```
{Objec.results ? Object.results.books.map(book =>(
<Book />
)) : null}
```

Comment: Hi @hilory ty! But since I’m using that and not the dot notation for what piece of the json array I need how can I get that? I’m connecting the parts of the array I want